# Laravel - get images from storage without /storage in the URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel 10 app and added an image upload. The image is getting uploaded to

```
/storage/app/public/user.name/image.jpg
```

The storage is also linked with: php artisan storage:link. I can see that the storage is linked correctly, since in the /public folder, I can see the link to /storage/app/public

Currently, I can get the image by visiting: `http://localhost:8000/storage/user.name/image.jpg`

However, I want the image to be visible under: `http://localhost:8000/user.name/image.jpg`.
At least thats how it worked for me in previous laravel apps.

Now for the filesystem. The env var was: `FILESYSTEM_DISK=local` and I changed it to `FILESYSTEM_DISK=public`.

I did that because the `disks` array in the filesystems.php tells me that "public" has the "root" at `storage_path('app/public')`, which seems right to me.

But I have the feeling that it does absolutely nothing, cause even if I add "s3" in there, I can see the image under the storage URL.

Not sure what to do here?

Comment: "At least thats how it worked for me in previous laravel apps." This is unlikely; the path you're seeing is the normal one. Why do you care about this, though?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the `url` key in `disks` in `config/filesystems.php`.

```
'disks' => [
// ...
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage', // change this. for example you can omit the '/storage'
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
// ...
];
```

Answer (score -2):

For that you'd have to link your public storage path using:
`php artisan storage:link`

This will create a symbolic link, check docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk